# Unhandled Exception with Azure serviceBusService

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-servicebus-queues

I'm trying to send a serviceBusQueue message from an API function in my Azure mobile-service and even though it successfully creates the queueService and the queue exists I get a nasty exception.  Any clue how I fix this?

I've attached the send code and stack trace.

```
function sendBusMessage(request, params, message, success)
{
  console.log(params);
  var queueService = azure.createServiceBusService(params.namespace,params.key);
  console.log(queueService);
  if (queueService)
  {
    queueService.sendQueueMessage('worker', message, function (error) 
    {
        if (!error) 
        {
            success();
        }
        else 
        {
            request.respond(statusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,error);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Exception stack:

An unhandled exception occurred. TypeError: Cannot set property 'body' of null
    at ServiceClient._performRequest.self._buildRequestOptions.operation (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\azure\lib\services\core\serviceclient.js:210:34)
    at ServiceClient._performRequest (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\azure\lib\services\core\serviceclient.js:264:7)
    at ServiceBusService.ServiceClient._initDefaultFilter.filter (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\azure\lib\services\core\serviceclient.js:534:7)
    at ServiceClient._performRequest (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\azure\lib\services\core\serviceclient.js:261:10)
    at ServiceBusServiceClient._buildRequestOptions (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\azure\lib\services\core\servicebusserviceclient.js:107:5)
    at Wrap.signRequest (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\azure\lib\services\serviceBus\wrap.js:69:5)
    at WrapTokenManager.getAccessToken (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\azure\lib\services\serviceBus\wraptokenmanager.js:76:5)
    at WrapService.wrapAccessToken.finalCallback (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\azure\lib\services\serviceBus\wrapservice.js:98:7)
    at ServiceClient._initDefaultFilter.filter (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\azure\lib\services\core\serviceclient.js:538:11)
    at WrapService.wrapAccessToken.processResponseCallback (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\azure\lib\services\serviceBus\wrapservice.js:101:5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are using the top level configuration from the Service Bus->Namespace not anything deeper in the tree. An incorrect access key will not throw a useful exception (like "Can't use a queue key to access a namespace") but instead produces the problem above.

Answer (score 2):

#### Namespace

The `namespace` for configuring Node.js is the one visible under `Service Bus` tab (that is pretty straightforward).

#### Access Key

Unfortunately it can be easily confused with access keys defined for the specific messaging capability instances (such as queues). Providing an invalid access key may result in a stacktrace like the one in question.

The `access key` which should be used for configuring Node.js is the one accessible from the `Connection Information` window. To get there, you need to navigate to the `Service Bus` main tab (one with the cloud icon), then click `Connection Information` button available from **the bar at the bottom**. It is the `Default Key` right beneath the `DEFAULT ISSUER` section.

#### Configuring Namespace and Access Key

Both `namespace` and `access key` can either be passed to `azure.createServiceBusService()` function directly, or (when configuring a Mobile Service) set via `AZURE_SERVICEBUS_NAMESPACE` and `AZURE_SERVICEBUS_ACCESS_KEY` keys in the `app settings` configuration section.